# PLS-00306 while trying to run an oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

I'm kind of new to this so forgive me if i made a mess here.
I created the following procedure -

```
create or replace procedure perform_trade
(p_trade_id number,
p_trade_amount number,
p_balances_id number,
v_out_random_coinid out number,
v_out_random_userid out number,
v_out_random_tradetype out varchar2,
v_out_current_balance out number
)
IS
BEGIN
SELECT ID into v_out_random_coinid from
(SELECT ID
FROM SQL_COINS_VIEW
ORDER BY dbms_random.value)
WHERE rownum = 1;
SELECT ID into v_out_random_userid from
(SELECT ID
FROM USERS
ORDER BY dbms_random.value)
WHERE rownum = 1;
SELECT TYPE into v_out_random_tradetype from
(SELECT TYPE
FROM TRADETYPES
ORDER BY dbms_random.value)
WHERE rownum = 1;
SELECT AMOUNT into v_out_current_balance from
BALANCES
WHERE USERID=v_out_random_userid
and COINID=v_out_random_coinid;
Insert into COINTRADER.trades (ID,USERID,COINID,AMOUNT,ACTIONTYPE,RATE)
Values (p_trade_id, v_out_random_userid, v_out_random_coinid, p_trade_amount, v_out_random_tradetype, (select value from SQL_COINS_VIEW where id=v_out_random_coinid ));
Commit;
Insert into COINTRADER.balances
Values (p_balances_id, v_out_random_userid, v_out_random_coinid, v_out_current_balance+(select total from trades where id=p_trade_id  ));
Commit;
End;
```

And tried to run it this way through PL/SQL developer-

```
DECLARE
v_num NUMBER:=1;
BEGIN
LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_num);
v_num := v_num + 1;
perform_trade
(TRADES_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 10),
BALANCES_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL);
DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(1);
EXIT WHEN v_num > 5;
END LOOP;
END;
```

But i get this error -

```
Error starting at line 45 in command:
DECLARE
v_num NUMBER:=1;
BEGIN
LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_num);
v_num := v_num + 1;
perform_trade
(TRADES_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 10),
BALANCES_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL);
DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(1);
EXIT WHEN v_num > 5;
END LOOP;
END;
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 7, column 1:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'PERFORM_TRADE'
ORA-06550: line 7, column 1:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your out variables are not present in the statement that calls the procedure.  Should be something like

```
perform_trade
(TRADES_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 10),
BALANCES_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
v_out_random_coinid ,
v_out_random_userid ,
v_out_random_tradetype,
v_out_current_balance);
```

Comment: Correct answer. You need to create space for the procedure to assign the output variables to.

Comment: DECLARE
v_num NUMBER:=1;
v_out_random_coinid NUMBER(10) ;
v_out_random_userid NUMBER(8);
v_out_random_tradetype VARCHAR2(10);
v_out_current_balance NUMBER(30);
BEGIN
LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_num);
v_num := v_num + 1;
perform_trade
(TRADES_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1, 10),
BALANCES_ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL,
v_out_random_coinid ,
v_out_random_userid ,
v_out_random_tradetype,
v_out_current_balance);
DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP(1);
EXIT WHEN v_num > 5;
END LOOP;
END;